# Hello, Please can someone assist me with in checking my code?..I try to generate a high freq signal (at least 150KHz) with Arduino Mega, CTC Mode

Tags: arduino-mega

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  TCCR2A = TCCR2A & B01010000 | B00000010 ; // CTC mode activated, Toggle OC2A
  TCCR2B = TCCR2B & B11110000 | B00000001;//Prescaller set
  TCNT2=0;//Start Counting ffrom 0
  OCR2A=127;//Set TOP value)
  
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: It may not be strictly necessary, but it would probably good to say what you're seeing instead of the expected signal.

Answer (score 4):

```cpp
TCCR2A = TCCR2A & B01010000 | B00000010 ; // CTC mode activated, Toggle OC2A
```

What you have here clears `TCCR2A`'s `COM2A1` but preserves its original `COM2A0`.

When I print out `TCCR2A` prior to modification, I see a value of `0x01` (COM2A is 0; both bits of it).

Printing out `TCCR2A` after you've manipulated it 0x02.  So, in `TCCR2A`, you
are winding up with zeros for your `COM2A1` and `COM2A0` bits, which is all
cases is "Normal port operation; OC2A disconnected".  That is, you're not going
to see whatever signal you might otherwise have configured to generate because
it just hasn't been routed to the (Arduino pin 10)/(gpio PB4)/OC2A

It's usually better to not rely on the bootloader and the start code and the
Arduino core to have left a hardware register in a particular state.

The following is probably closer to what you intended:

```cpp
TCCR2A = B01010000 | B00000010 ; // CTC mode activated, Toggle OC2A
```

It's still not entirely correct to the problem description (not the correct frequency), but it does send a signal out of the Arduino MEGA's digital pin 10.  It also is configured to toggle OC2B, so unless you wanted that:

```cpp
TCCR2A = B01000000 | B00000010 ; // CTC mode activated, Toggle OC2A
```

This can be made more readable by using the bit field names for the given:

```cpp
TCCR2A = 
      (1 << COM2A0)  // CTC mode activated (note COM2A1 is zero)
    | (2 <<  WGM20); // lower two bits of WGM value 2
```

You can do this same sort of thing for `TCCR2B`. And likewise, it is best that you don't rely on the previous value of `TCCR2B`.

With `OCR2A = 127;`, you are toggling (reaching a **half**-period) every 128/16,000,000 seconds, or a 8 uS half-period, for a 16 uS period. Generating 62.5 KHz, which is below your target 150 KHz.  Knowing it's half-periods, an `OCR2A` of 63 gets you to 125 KHz.

An `OCR2A` of 52 or less gets you into the greater than 150 kHz range, at least if we take your 16 MHz clock rate very seriously. You might need to be a little lower to be sure.